# insert data from table into another table if don't exist

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, sqlitemanager

hi so that's my problem :(i'm working in eclipse with java )
i have this table phone(id,mark,reference,OS)
and i have  3 seller vend1,vend2,vend3(id,mark,reference,os,price)
i want insert all data from vend1 and vend2 and vend3  into the table phone without price so i want to insert the phone if don't exist in the table phone because 2 or 3 seller can have the same phone but i want to insert just one in table phone.
hope you can help.

Comment: Please format your question according to posting guidelines.

Comment: What db are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a series on insert-select statements:

```
INSERT INTO phone
SELECT is, mark, reference, os
FROM   vend1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   phone
                   WHERE  phone.id = vend1.id)
```

Similarly, you could create statements for the `vend2` and `vend3` tables.

Comment: Use the merge . It will let you delete rows on the target table based on the where clause. You can check here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) statement. You can accomplish your requirement with merge.